# Can Missing Data ever be considered as "Informative"?

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, model, cart

I have always had the following question: **Can Missing Data ever be considered as "Informative"?**

Often we view missing data as problematic, and either discard missing data or try to use imputation methods to remedy this problem - but can missing data ever be considered "informative"? To illustrate this question, consider the following example where there is a university that consists of local students and exchange students. At the start of the year, all students have to fill out a questionnaire in the local language (assume that local students speak the local language better than the exchange students). At the end of the year, all students have to write an exam where they are tested on their proficiency of the local language ("pass" or "fail"). Let's imagine that the exchange students had difficulties filling the questionnaire (they left many questions empty) and also performed poorly on the language exam. Using the R programming language, I tried to simulate some data that corresponds to the questionnaire and the exam results:

```
set.seeed(123)

sleep <- rnorm(500,0,0)
hours_exer <- rnorm(500,0,0)
daily_calories <- rnorm(500,0,0)

exam_score <- c("pass","fail")
exam_score <- sample(exam_score, 500, replace=TRUE, 
                        prob=c(0.1, 0.9))
exam_score <- as.factor(exam_score)

student_status <- as.factor("exchange")

data_1 <- data.frame(sleep, hours_exer, daily_calories, exam_score, student_status)

sleep <- rnorm(100,8,1)
hours_exer <- rnorm(100,5,1)
daily_calories <- rnorm(100,2000,100)

exam_score <- c("pass","fail")
exam_score <- sample(exam_score, 100, replace=TRUE, 
                        prob=c(0.1, 0.9))
exam_score <- as.factor(exam_score)


student_status <- as.factor("exchange")

data_2 <- data.frame(sleep, hours_exer, daily_calories, exam_score, student_status)

exchange_student_data <- rbind(data_1, data_2)


sleep <- rnorm(10000,8,1)
hours_exer <- rnorm(10000,5,1)
daily_calories <- rnorm(10000,2000,100)

exam_score <- c("pass","fail")
exam_score <- sample(exam_score, 10000, replace=TRUE, 
                        prob=c(0.8, 0.2))
exam_score <- as.factor(exam_score)


student_status <- as.factor("local")

local_student_data <- data.frame(sleep, hours_exer, daily_calories, exam_score, student_status)

all_students <- rbind(local_student_data, exchange_student_data)
```

The data would look something like this:

```
head(all_students)

     sleep hours_exer daily_calories exam_score student_status
1 8.297016   5.420062       1999.361       fail          local
2 7.404503   4.925385       2088.698       fail          local
3 8.353541   6.270823       2077.302       pass          local
4 6.747754   6.617365       1994.906       pass          local
5 7.406585   4.913556       1893.967       fail          local
6 8.358945   5.196405       2039.819       pass          local
```

As we can see, there tends to be a lot of "missing values" amongst the exchange students compared to the local students (e.g. it is impossible to sleep 0 hours a day and eat 0 calories):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p1 <- ggplot(data=all_students, aes(x=sleep, group=student_status, fill=student_status)) +
    geom_density(adjust=1.5) + ggtitle("Sleep : Local Students vs Exchange Students")

p2 <- ggplot(data=all_students, aes(x=hours_exer, group=student_status, fill=student_status)) +
    geom_density(adjust=1.5) + ggtitle("Hours Exercising : Local Students vs Exchange Students")

p3 <- ggplot(data=all_students, aes(x=daily_calories, group=student_status, fill=student_status)) + geom_density(adjust=1.5) + ggtitle(" Daily Calories : Local Students vs Exchange Students")

p4 <- ggplot(data=all_students, aes(x=daily_calories, group=student_status, fill=student_status)) + geom_density(adjust=1.5) + ggtitle(" Daily Calories : Local Students vs Exchange Students")


 m = data.frame(all_students[,c(4,5)] %>%
    group_by(student_status, exam_score) %>%
    summarise(count = n()))

p5 <- ggplot(m, aes(fill=exam_score, y=count, x=student_status)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + ggtitle("Exam Scores : Local Students vs Exchange Students")
```

[image]

If we were to fit a Decision Tree (e.g. CART) model, we would find that the "absence of data" is actually for the statistical model:

**1) With Student Status**

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

model1 <- rpart(exam_score~., data = all_students)

rpart.plot(model1)
```

[image]

**2) Without Student Status**

```
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

model2 <- rpart(exam_score~., data = all_students[,-5])

rpart.plot(model2)
```

[image]

**3) Standard Approach: Missing Data Removed**

```
  all_students[all_students == 0] <- NA
all_students <- na.omit(all_students)
    
     model3 <- rpart(exam_score~., data = all_students)
```

In all cases, statistical models were successfully fit to the datasets even though there was a large amount of missing data. In normal circumstances, rows containing missing data are removed (e.g. `na.omit`) - but I was wondering if in certain cases, missing data (note: in this case, the data was not "0" but genuinely "missing") can actually serve as legitimate statistical indicator and useful information for statistical models.

**My Question:** Are there any cases in the real world where missing data can genuinely be used within statistical models? Or is the example I have identified above too ideal and unlikely to ever occur in the real world?

Note: I also assume that in the real world, we will not always know the logical relationships between missing data and the outcome variable.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to grasp because the term "informative missing" has a special meaning in statistics. It describes a special type of missingness that is very hard to deal with.

Comment: Because there are many examples that can be offered, and the question is a useful one, I have made this a CW thread.

Comment: @ whuber: thank you for your reply! Can you please tell me what is a "cw thread"? Thank you!

Comment: @ Michael M: Thank you for your reply! Does this special type of missingness have a name? Thank you!